# ¿Para que es la palabra checked en C#?

Tags: c#, sintaxis

> Traducción de la pregunta [**What is the C# “checked” keyword for?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709495/what-is-the-c-sharp-checked-keyword-for)
>   en [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com)

Acabo de encontrar esta palabra clave por primera vez. ¿Qué hace y cuándo debe usarse?

```
int multiply(int i, int j)
{
    return checked(i * j);
}
```

Comment: Cuando tienes dudas relacionadas al lenguaje el primer punto de partida deberia ser la doc oficial https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked ali lo explica bien completo y con ejemplos

Comment: no entiendo, generas la pregunta y te la respondes, cual es el sentido de hacer eso ? ademas basado en traducciones de otras respuestas

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Creo que la idea de StackOverflow en general, es funcionar a modo de base de datos de preguntas/respuestas que puedan ayudar a todos los usuarios, no sólo la que realiza la pregunta, por eso (creo yo) que existe la opción de responder tu propia pregunta.. Sin embargo, no creo que sea el lugar para hacer ese comentario, me parece que para eso existe [Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @LeandroTuttini respecto a traducir otra respuesta, no crees que está bueno hacer llegar una útil y buena pregunta/respuesta a SOes, donde posiblemente hay mucha gente que no tiene un buen dominio del inglés, y viene acá a sacarse las dudas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Traducción a la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20709496/5213794) de [McGarnagle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001985/mcgarnagle)

[`checked`](http://%20%20%20%20checked) es un bloque que permite el desbordamiento aritmético, normalmente, si en una operación de enteros se excede el valor máximo o mínimo que el tipo puede manejar, la operación se procesa igualmente, y el resultado simplemente cambia como un odómetro.

Por ejemplo:

```
byte b = byte.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(b);       // 255  (11111111)
Console.WriteLine(++b);     // 0    (00000000)
```

Colocando el snippet anterior en un bloque [`checked`](http://%20%20%20%20checked) se prevendrá el desbordamiento, y en su lugar, se disparará un [`OverflowException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.OverflowException.%2523ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

```
checked
{
    byte b = byte.MaxValue;
    Console.WriteLine(b);               // b=255
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(++b);
    }
    catch (OverflowException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);   // "Operación que terminó en un desbordamiento." 
                                        // b = 255
    }
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta que hay una opción del compilador que activa el "checking" por defecto, también existe una el bloque [`unchecked`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(unchecked_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue), que lo que hace es prevenir el chequeo de desbordamiento.

En cuanto al uso, la verificación de desbordamiento debe usarse con moderación, como es el caso del manejo de excepciones en general. Para verificar un desbordamiento en tiempo de ejecución, es significativamente más rápido (como un orden de magnitud) hacer una verificación simple, en lugar de activar la verificación de desbordamiento:

```
int multiply(int i, int j)
{ 
    if ((long)i * (long)j > int.MaxValue)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("overflow");
    return i*j;
}
```

Esto puede hacerse incluso para Int64/long, usando `BigInteger`

```
long multiply(long i, long j)
{ 
    if (new System.Numerics.BigInteger(i) + j > long.MaxValue)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("overflow");
    return i*j;
}
```

<sup><sub>Por favor, cualquiera siéntase libre de realizar correcciones/modificaciones en la traducción.</sub></sup>